# Branch.io Pass Custom Data with Install

Tags: ios, objective-c, branch.io

I am using Branch.io to link installs back to ad campaigns. Our setup uses Branch simply for install attribution after which the install metadata is sent back to our app via webhook. I want to pass some custom parameters with an install event so that we can tie the install to a specific user (in our own system, not using Branch's analytics). My initial thought was to make a call to Branch SDK's `setRequestMetaData()` function like this:

```
[[Branch getInstance] setRequestMetadataKey: @"userId" value: 123];
```

The problem is that I'm not seeing that data within the Install payload that is sent via the webhook. Here is what the webhook payload looks like:

```
{
    "name":  "INSTALL",
    "user_data":  {
        "os": "IOS",
        "os_version": "11.4",
        "environment": "FULL_APP",
        "platform": "IOS_APP",
        "idfv": "masked",
        "limit_ad_tracking": false,
        "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML,
         like Gecko) Mobile/15F79",
        "ip": "xxx.xx.xx.xx",
        "country": "US",
        "language": "EN",
        "sdk_version": "0.25.0",
        "app_version": "2.6.3",
        "brand": "Apple",
        "model": "iPhone7,2",
        "geo_dma_code": 501,
        "geo_country_code": "US"
    },
    "last_attributed_touch_data":  {
        "~feature": "marketing",
        "~id": 464580903277040904,
        "~campaign": "test-campaign",
        "~channel": "Facebook",
        "+url": "https: //subdomain.test-app.link/branch-test",
        "$desktop_url": "http: //www.sample.com",
        "$marketing_title": "Test Link",
        "~creation_source": 1,
        "~marketing": true,
        "+click_timestamp": 1528297685,
        "$one_time_use": false,
        "$android_url": "http: //www.sample.com",
        "$ios_passive_deepview": "branch_passive_default",
        "testTag": "testValue",
        "~tags": [
            "123"
        ],
        "+via_features": [
            "QUICK_LINKS"
        ]
    },
    "timestamp":  1528297898204
}
```

Is there another way to pass custom data with a Branch install event?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they support that use case.

This is from their docs (see [Track users](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/)):

```
// login
[[Branch getInstance] setIdentity:@"your_user_id"];

// logout
[[Branch getInstance] logout];
```

Note that this is against GDPR to do this without prior user's consent, so if you have users in Europe, they need to have an opt-in UI and an explanation.

Comment: I thought about this approach but I really just want to track the Install. `setIdentity` should really be correlated with a login event. Since users aren't logged in the first time they launch the app after install, what I really meant in my question is that I need to send some sort of anonymousId, not a real userId that corresponds to our app.

Comment: It doesn't have to. If you have some "userId" that identifies you user, you can use `setIdentity` with it. If later on the user decides to log in (let's say to get more functionality), then he either users the same userId (so previous `setIdentity` should be fine), or he enters a different user name, and so you can call `setIdentity` again with a new userId (just as if the user logs out and logs in with a different name). In any case I don't think that "setIdentity" sends an event, so for tracking logins, you'll have to create a custom event (as they show in "Track events").

Comment: Thanks for the help! We aren't trying to track logins, we're really only trying to track Installs (i.e. first launch). Our new workaround is to send a custom event if Branch param `+is_first_session` is true. That way we can get the marketing attribution data into our own system without having to rely too heavily on Branch.

Answer (score 0):

Any request metadata should be in the top-level JSON dictionary, `custom_data` next to `last_attributed_touch_data` in the webhook body. Are you calling `setRequestMetadata` before the SDK initialization? Ensure that the key/values are being sent on every SDK request when `setDebug()` mode is called. Here's the example body: https://docs.branch.io/pages/exports/ua-webhooks/#sample-webhook-post-body-syntax

Comment: Yes, I am calling `setRequestMetadata` before initializing Branch. I also saw that sample post body in the docs. Unfortunately, and as you can see in the json payload that I included in my question, it's still not there. Oh well, we've figured out how to do it another way using custom events and it's probably a more flexible solution anyways.